# HDMI display not detected in nvidia Geforce 9300 GS

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu in my Sony Vaio VGN-Z31XN with nVidia GeForce 9300 GS.

When i tried to connect it to my Samsung television through the HDMI cable, it seems that the laptop can't seem to detect the display in settings as you can see here:

https://gyazo.com/e6a0ed03843f06f7ef660a2e3e9faf46

After this, i installed bumblebee and in nvidia x server settings it doesn't show the option of "X Server Display Information" as you can see by my printscreen in:

https://gyazo.com/64b055821a26aac22156b2d55907946c

Do you know what might be the problem? How i can see the display option in the nvidia x server? I tried to install Prime as well, but when i restarted after the install the laptop when started just showed a black screen. So i have also some problem with installing nvidia prime drivers.

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I still use my old VGN-21VN with the same GeForce9300 GS. Many years ago, it worked fine, but some day it just didn't (probably due to an update). See also the thread here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578004